# Syntax error with NodeJS and HTTP

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.writeHead(" This is just a start.. Remember what u thought of it.");
    reponse.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

This is my JS code in a file named `server.js` which I wanted to execute through Node.js, but it's giving an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The path of the file, `server.js` is in D Drive, same as where I installed Node.js. What should I do ?

Comment: Are you just double clicking the js file, or running with node somehow on purpose?  You might just be running it with the Windows script host.

Comment: What commands are you running? Whats the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: That second thing is not a valid header to write.

Comment: @Dandy. I am running " node server.js" on Node.js

Comment: @tadman I am not getting what are you saying. Please elaborate. I am new to Node.js

Comment: `writeHead` is used for writing headers only and " This is just a start..." is not a valid HTTP header. As Loksly points out, don't bother with this code, you're wasting your time here. At the very least use Express. It gives you the building blocks you'll need to make something actually useful, not just marginally functional.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(" This is just a start.. Remember what u thought of it.");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

Save it in a file named "server.js" and run it with:

```
node server.js
```

Comment: I recommend give a try [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) for an easier way to write an http server.

Comment: I also highly recommend ExpressJS. Writing this stuff versus the core HTTP  driver is a complete waste of time.

Comment: I did that. I saved the file with name "server.js" and tried to run with the command  " node server.js". Thats when the error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a typo in your question but you use `reponse` instead of `response`:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.writeHead(" This is just a start.. Remember what u thought of it.");
  reponse.end(); // <------
}).listen(8888);
```